# How to find total views in a YouTube PlayList

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find the total number of views of all videos in a playlist I own in YouTube. I can see that a "total views" number is posted under the playlist name. However this appears to be the number of views generated by entering the playlist first. When I add up the number of views of individual videos I get a substantially larger number because, I assume, most of videos are watched by following a link other than the playlist.

In searching for an answer I see two suggestions

1. using the following JS in the YT console

```
ytInitialData.header.playlistHeaderRenderer.viewCountText.simpleText
```

But this just gives the same number that is available under the playlist name.

2. using the following

```
var totalViews = 0;
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('ytd-playlist-video-renderer');
for (var i= 0; i < videos.length; i++)  {
    var viewsElement = videos[i].querySelector('#metadata > span:nth- child(1)');
    if (viewsElement !== null) {
        var views = viewsElement.textContent.trim().replace(/\D/g,'');
        totalViews += parseInt(views);
    }
}
console.log('Total views of all videos in the playlist: ' + totalViews);
```

But this gives a total count of 0.

Comment: Can you provide a working demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with this script and it seems to work on the browser. I couldn't figure out any possible edge cases. I also assumed that the total views will never exceed the maximum safe integer in javascript. Also note that the views that say like `1.3M` `560K` are approximated/rounded. So you can never get the exact view count from a playlist. Only an approximation. However it will be accurate if the playlist has videos with views less than 1000.

```js
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('ytd-playlist-video-renderer');
const convertViews = (views) => {
  let num = parseFloat(views);
  if (views.includes("K")) {
    num *= 1000;
  } else if (views.includes("M")) {
    num *= 1000000;
  } else if (views.includes("B")) {
    num *= 1000000000;
  }
  return num;
}

let totalViews = 0
videos.forEach((vid) => {
    const views = vid.querySelector('#video-info > span:nth-child(1)')?.textContent.split(' ')[0] || '0'
    const converted = convertViews(views)
    totalViews += converted
})

console.log(totalViews)
```