# How to find the total time all videos of a YT playlist have been viewed

Tags: youtube-api, playlist

Suppose a YouTube PlayList P has videos v1,v2,... . I want to find the total time any video from that list has been viewed prior to now (or prior to time T). Is there a JavaScript that I can run in the console to do this?

I see YT analytics provides the average view length for each individual video. But I do not see that information for a playlist.

Here is my partial attempt:

```
var totalTime = 0;
var videos = document.querySelectorAll('ytd-playlist-video-renderer');
videos.forEach(function(video) {
totalTime += parseInt(video.querySelector('.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time- 
 status-renderer').innerText.split(':').pop());
 });
console.log('Total time: ' + totalTime + ' seconds');
```

A related question on the [number of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992593/how-to-find-total-views-in-a-youtube-playlist).

Comment: @cmgchess  This is the closest attempt I found  https://ytplaylist-len.sharats.dev/

Comment: I also had written a script to get playlist length. But for long playlist it will only take the lengths of the videos rendered on the ui

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Wd77WW this was written sometime back so couldnt test again since I'm on mobile atm. I think "want to find the total time any video from that list has been viewed prior to now (or prior to time T)" is not handled here. Also didn't understand it very well can you elaborate

Comment: i dont know if it has the details of when you actually watched the video, it however should be possible to get the fraction of time watched in a video from the red line

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Wd77WW with progress as well